# TypeError: raw_input() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python-3.x, input, arguments, user-input, raw-input

I was trying to find the average height of n number of children. I wanted to make the input says "Enter the height of children number A", where A is an arbitrary integer (1, 2, 3,...) which indicate the A-th children. I have designed my code this way, which somehow ended up to this error (shown in the title). I would appreciate any help :).

```
jmlh_anak = int(input("Enter n number of children : "))
A = 1
jmlh_tinggi = 0

while (A <= jmlh_anak):
  nilai_tinggi = int(input("Enter the height of children number ", str(A)))
  jmlh_tinggi += nilai_tinggi
  A += 1

rtrt_tinggi = jmlh_tinggi / jmlh_anak
print("The average of the children's height will be", rtrt_tinggi)
```

I was expecting the input for the children's height would say "Enter the height of children number 1 : " for example.

Comment: You need to build a single string for the prompt argument.

Comment: Yes, but I was trying on how do I make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
nilai_tinggi = int(input("Enter the height of children number %d" %A))
```

for string formatting.

Comment: Really helped, I appreciate your help ^-^.

Comment: @AumediWibisana I am glad it helped, please accept my answer if this is enough of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

nilai_tinggi = int(input(f"Enter the height of children number {A}: "))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Since string and integers cannot be connected together directly you need to convert the integer into a string first and then use it in the input statement.

you can use the statement as:

```
nilai_tinggi = int(input("Enter the height of children number "+ str(A)))
```